# Change the color of an element when text is typed in input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-input

I'm looking for a way to change the style of an element, (like the `<body>`) when not just text, but specific number like "5214" or something is entered in an `<input>`. With my current code, a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerText') gets thrown. How can I fix it? The error is on line 3. I saw something like this on an ADT security system panel, but was instead using an `<input type="hidden">`. There were using 4 `<span>` elements too.

HTML CSS JS

```js
const inputField = document.getElementsByClassName("doSomething");

if(inputField[0].innerText = "5214") {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.backgroundColor = "lime";
}
```

```css
input {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<label>Numbers only:</label><input type="text" onkeypress="return (event.charCode !=8 && event.charCode ==0 || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57))" />
<br>
<label>Numbers and decimal points only:</label>
<input type="text" onkeypress="return (event.charCode !=8 && event.charCode ==0 || ( event.charCode == 46 || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)))" />
```

Comment: Neither of the `input` elements in your example have the `.doSomething` class - is that correct? If so, please edit the HTML to show the fields the event should happen on.

Comment: You need to use the `value` of the input instead of the `innerText`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11563667/735398

Comment: To add on to the other issues, you have `inputField[0].innerText = "5214"`  as your condition. I don't think this is what you want to do, because that is the assignment operator and you want to compare both using the `==` operator. Please see my answer below for more details about more issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems to address in that code.

- In your HTML, the input tags aren't specified with a class name, but you are saying that they are of class `doSomething` in your javascript. Thus, there are currently NO elements of class `doSomething`, which is why `document.getElementsByClassName("doSomething")` returns `undefined`.
- When your condition in the if statement is `inputField[0].innerText = "5214"`, you are not comparing both values to check if they are equal. You are assigning. **Wrong operator.** For comparison, you need to use `==`.
- Also, to get the text inside an input element, you can't use the `innerText` property, since they don't work like text elements. Instead, you need to use `value`.
- Doing `document.getElementsByTagName("body")` would return an array, not the only body element you have, because you could have many. So, presuming you only have one body tag, you could do `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`.
- You must check the value of the input AFTER `keyup`, not `keypress`, because the value doesn't change before the `keypress`. It only does that before `keyup`. So you are checking the previous value with `keypress`, not the current. Therefore, you must use `onkeyup`.
- BTW, when you say `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style`, as long as you have only one body tag (which you should), you should instead say `document.body.style`. Obviously, the second one is easier, simpler and makes more sense than the first.

Here is the final code which works:

```js
const inputField = document.getElementsByClassName("doSomething");

function check() {
  if(inputField[0].value == "5214") {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lime";
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Numbers only:</label>
<input class="doSomething" type="text" onkeyup="check()" onkeypress="return (event.charCode !=8 && event.charCode ==0 || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57))"/>
<br>
<label>Numbers and decimal points only:</label>
<input class="doSomething" type="text" onkeyup="check()"  onkeypress="return (event.charCode !=8 && event.charCode ==0 || ( event.charCode == 46 || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)))"/>
```

Comment: The addition of the `onkeypress` attribute was for making it only allow/contain numbers. Decimal points are allowed for the second input field too.

Comment: @ChristianSamu Ah, I did not notice that properly, sorry. I have edited my answer to support that. So, now, it should work they way you asked for.

Comment: @ChristianSamu If you type "5214", the background goes lime. But then, if you change it by, say, adding an "8" to the end, do you need the program to go back to a white background?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with your answer and it stayed lime.

Comment: @ChristianSamu I have fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the class **doSomething** is missing in your inputs and for body selector

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.backgroundColor = "lime";
```

add [0] index for it then your code will run successfully...

as give below of my code.

**Html Code**

```
<label>Numbers only:</label>
    <input type="text" class="doSomething" onkeyup="changeColor()" />
    <br>
    <label>Numbers and decimal points only:</label>
    <input type="text" class="doSomething" onkeyup="changeColor()" />
```

**Javascript Code**

```
<script>
    const inputField = document.getElementsByClassName("doSomething");
    console.log(inputField[0])

    let changeColor = () => {
        if (inputField[0].value == "5214") {
            let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            body.style.backgroundColor = "lime";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure the condition in the if statement would be `inputField[0].innerText = "5214"`, if the questioner wants to compare if both values are equal?

Comment: Oh sorry, for this we have the check condition for input's value not inner text and instead of returning something just call a function that check for inputs value, I just update my answer.